# Unable to use FBSDKGraphRequest with Parse login

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I'm using Parse to login with facebook on my app.

This is my code :

```
    //set permissions required
    let permissionsArray = ["user_about_me"]
    //log in
    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissionsArray, block: { (pUser, pError) -> Void in


        //if user is correctly loggin
        if pUser != nil && pError == nil{


            //request facebook for more informations
            var request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)

            request.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                NSLog("\(error)")

            })

        }
    })
```

I am correctly log in with parse, but when i'am asking for my informations, have always have this message :

```
com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 2500;
            message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Facebook SDK for login, i make a Parse login with returned token and i can get my user's informations after that.

I have solved my issue with this code :

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(["user_about_me"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in

        if let resultLogin : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result as? FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult{

            //if no error
            if error == nil
                && resultLogin.grantedPermissions.contains("user_about_me"){
                    var accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
                    var expiration = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().expirationDate
                    var facebookID = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().userID

                    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithFacebookId(facebookID, accessToken: accessToken, expirationDate: expiration, block: { (pUser, pError) -> Void in

                        //if user is correctly loggin
                        if pUser != nil && pError == nil{


                            //request facebook for more informations
                            var request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)

                            request.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                                NSLog("\(error)")

                            })

                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    })
```